# Android relative layout - align a widget parent right based on another widget's visibliity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to design a layout like this:
[image]

Text1 and Text2 are two TextViews always aligned to parent right.

In some scenarios Text2 gets hidden and Text1 should replace it. But I am unable to achieve it using layout parameters. I tried to search the site but could not get any help.

One way doing it might be to modify the alignment of Text1 based on visibility of Text2 programmatically but I want to know if there is any way of achieving it using layout params.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use `setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: The widget (Text2) gets hidden at runtime by calling setVisibility(View.GONE) itself. After that widget Text1 should come at its place but thats not happening :(

Comment: Use TextView.GONE, Simply you need to call text2.setVisibility(TextView.GONE), this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a linear layout with it's gravity set to **RIGHT** e.g.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you have a freedom of hiding anyone or both text view without disturbing the layout.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
      [...]>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="+id/text2"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And when you are to remove text2 use

> setVisibility(View.GONE);